# Sum the count for each countries for that month per month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list a 2000 row dataset with a countries in lists followed by their count. I want to sum of all the counts by exploding the lists and grouping them together for each month, every month.

```
df_grouped=df.pivot_table(index=('month','month_int', 'year'),values='views',aggfunc='max')

count   period_start    year    month_int   month   Countries
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  []
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['Spain', 'Brazil', 'Porgutal', 'France', 'Romania', 'Germany#', 'Norway']
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['Spain', 'Brazil', 'Porgutal', 'France', 'Romania', 'Germany#', 'Norway']
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['Porgutal', 'Canada', 'USA', 'Croatia', 'Egypt', 'Netherlands', 'Swizerland', 'Japan']
2       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['China', 'India', 'Vietnam']
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['Indai', ' Pakistan', 'Mongolia']
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['Indai', ' Pakistan', 'Mongolia']
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['Indai', ' Pakistan', 'Mongolia']
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  []
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['Germany', 'Spain', 'China', 'USA']
6       06/08/2018      2018    6           August  ['Germany', 'Spain', 'China', 'USA']
1       06/08/2018      2018    6           Sept    ['Germany', 'Spain', 'China', 'USA']
5       06/08/2018      2018    6           Sept    ['Germany', 'Spain', 'China', 'USA']
4       06/08/2018      2018    6           Sept    ['Germany', 'Spain', 'China', 'USA']
....
```

Im not sure how I can explode the countries topic, sum their count for each row and group them by countries.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.explode()` and `.groupby()`. You need to `reset_index()` to make it a dataframe and pass `name='Countries Count'` or any name different than `Countries`; otherwise, you will get an error, since the column name already exists:

```
df = (df.explode('Countries')
      .groupby(['year','month','Countries'])['Countries'].count().reset_index(name='Countries Count'))
df
Out[1]: 
    year   month    Countries  Countries Count
0   2018  August     Pakistan                3
1   2018  August       Brazil                2
2   2018  August       Canada                1
3   2018  August        China                3
4   2018  August      Croatia                1
5   2018  August        Egypt                1
6   2018  August       France                2
7   2018  August      Germany                2
8   2018  August     Germany#                2
9   2018  August        Indai                3
10  2018  August        India                1
11  2018  August        Japan                1
12  2018  August     Mongolia                3
13  2018  August  Netherlands                1
14  2018  August       Norway                2
15  2018  August     Porgutal                3
16  2018  August      Romania                2
17  2018  August        Spain                4
18  2018  August   Swizerland                1
19  2018  August          USA                3
20  2018  August      Vietnam                1
21  2018    Sept        China                3
22  2018    Sept      Germany                3
23  2018    Sept        Spain                3
24  2018    Sept          USA                3
```

Comment: What I trying to get is the 'Countries Count' to be the sum of the count for a country for that month. Eg Germany in September would have 10.

Comment: @Arron Does this give you the correct answer? `df = (df.explode('Countries')
          .groupby(['year','month','Countries'])['count'].count().reset_index(name='Countries Count'))
    df`

Comment: It says 'column not found - count' even though its there.

Comment: It’s probably on the index. Before the code above do df=df.reset_index()

Comment: I tried replacing ['count'].count() with .agg(['count']). That's not working either.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(r"dataset.csv") df=df.reset_index()  df = (df.explode('Countries').groupby(['year','month','Countries'])['count'].count().reset_index(name='Countries Count'))`   


The error is line 228, in __getitem__     raise KeyError(f"Column not found: {key}") KeyError: 'Column not found: count'